# SQL Server syntax about WHERE clause?

Tags: sql-server

This is my query in SQLServer:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SerialNo) AS Rownum,
    SerialNo, TimeLastTransaction, TimeLastVisit
FROM dbo.Terminals
WHERE SerialNo = 'FD-2FDSF-D34R-58F';
```

Is there way after WHERE clause SerialNo to be IN range of items, not equal to some item.

For example:

```
WHERE SerialNo in ['FD-2FDSF-D34R-58F', 'FC-2FDSG-D46R-58G', etc]
```

Comment: *"Is there way after WHERE clause SerialNo to be IN range of items, not equal to some item."* What does this mean..? Take the time to elaborate on your problem. Give sample data, and expected results.

Comment: Check out the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/search-condition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). And if you still have a question show some sample data and desired results (as formatted text).

Comment: Thank you Dale K, i really didn't consider it well. I take the note!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SerialNo) AS Rownum,
    SerialNo, TimeLastTransaction, TimeLastVisit
FROM dbo.Terminals
WHERE SerialNo in ('FD-2FDSF-D34R-58F','FC-2FDSG-D46R-58G');
```